# Laravel 5.0 functional test database

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I have app which uses laravel 5.0 and phpunit 4.8.
I have test, which looks like this:

```
$this->call('POST', 'api/get_user_by_id', [
            'token' => 'token',
            'user_id' => 3,
        ]);
```

It connects to may main database and get data from it. But I want test connect to other, test database and work with it. How can I do it?

Comment: For just that test case or for all of your tests?

Comment: For all my tests. I have several tests. I want all of them working with test db

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your test environment in your `phpunit.xml` file:

```
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    <env name="DB_HOST" value="localhost"/>
    <env name="DB_PORT" value="3306"/>
    <env name="DB_USERNAME" value="username"/>
    <env name="DB_PASSWORD" value="password"/>
</php>
```